# Creating SSIS package using C# script to load data from Salesforce using BULK API

Tags: c#, rest, curl, ssis, salesforce

I am trying to create a SSIS package which can be used to load Sales Force objects data in our warehouse. I am doing research from last 2 weeks, however, not getting any method which i can implement and work on.

I came across CURL, but that too cant be used due to certain limitations.
Can anyone help me here on how exactly I get this.
Below is the link which i was referring recently:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm

I am able to get serverURL and Session ID details through SOAP in SSIS script, which can be used for further process, however, not able to work on the next step.

I appreciate all help!!!

Comment: Please post your script code and point out where the error is.

Comment: Have you tried using the REST API?